# wicket redirect to another page and set Cookie

Tags: java, wicket

Hi I want to redirect to aonther page and also set some Cookie at the same time. none of the methods I found so for don't offer any feature like this.

I found:

```
 throw new RedirectToUrlException(..)
 throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(..)
```

but they cant do any thing about Cookie ( I think ).

Anybody has any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Also check org.apache.wicket.NonResettingRestartException. It doesn't reset the request headers, so cookies are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `cookie.setSecure(true);`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Ok `org.apache.wicket.Component.setResponsePage(...)` works !!!:)